# Cube writeback tables not updating some times

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code. This code will check the values in 2 columns and update the cubes/Writeback tables.
Most of the times all the 4 cubes/Writeback tables are updated. Very rare, FINANCE cubes (2nd for loop of the If block) are not updated. I am not able to reproduce the issue and unable to find out where the issue is exactly because most of the times update happens.
Any help is much appreciated.

```
enter code here
n = FreeFile()
Open "C:\Users\sree\Desktop\test5.text" For Output As #n
s = Application.UserName

Print #n, s
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
If Range("DB").Text = "Finance - Current FY Finance - Consol" Then
   cn.Open "Data Source=XXXXXX;Provider=MSOLAP.8;Initial Catalog=FINANCE - CURRENT FY"
   For Each cellX In Sheets("Data").Range("trans")
       If cellX.Value <> "" And cellX.Offset(0, 6).Value <> cellX.Offset(0, 7).Value Then
          s = CStr(cellX.Value) & ";Changed Value: " &    CStr(cellX.Offset(0, 6).Value) & ";DB value: " &               CStr(cellX.Offset(0, 7).Value)
          Print #n, s
          uMDX = ""
          uMDX = uMDX + "UPDATE CUBE [Finance - Consol] SET ([Measures].[Amount]"
          uMDX = uMDX + ",[Movements].[Monthly Movement].[Financial Day].&[" & cellX.Offset(0, 
                 -3).Value & "]"
          uMDX = uMDX + ",[Transaction Detail].[Transaction ID].&[" & cellX.Value & "]"
          uMDX = uMDX + ") = " & cellX.Offset(0, -2).Value
          uMDX = uMDX + " USE_EQUAL_ALLOCATION"
          UpdateStatement = uMDX
          s = uMDX
          Print #n, s
          cn.Execute UpdateStatement
          uMDX = ""
          uMDX = uMDX + "UPDATE CUBE [Finance - Divisional] SET ([Measures].[Amount]"
          uMDX = uMDX + ",[Movements].[Monthly Movement].[Financial Day].&[" & cellX.Offset(0, 
                -3).Value & "]"
          uMDX = uMDX + ",[Transaction Detail].[Transaction ID].&[" & cellX.Value & "]"
          uMDX = uMDX + ") = " & cellX.Offset(0, -2).Value
          uMDX = uMDX + " USE_EQUAL_ALLOCATION"
          UpdateStatement = uMDX
          s = uMDX
          Print #n, s
          cn.Execute UpdateStatement
          ctr = ctr + 1
       End If
   Next cellX

   Sheets("Data").Calculate
   If ctr > 0 Then
      CommitStatement = "COMMIT TRAN"
      cn.Execute CommitStatement
   End If
   cn.Close
   cn.Open "Data Source=XXXXX;Provider=MSOLAP.8;Initial Catalog=FINANCE"

   For Each cellX In Sheets("Data").Range("trans")
   If cellX.Value <> "" And cellX.Offset(0, 6).Value <> cellX.Offset(0, 7).Value Then
    s = CStr(cellX.Value) & ";Changed Value: " & CStr(cellX.Offset(0, 6).Value) & ";DB value: " & CStr(cellX.Offset(0, 7).Value)
    Print #n, s
    uMDX = ""
    uMDX = uMDX + "UPDATE CUBE [Finance - Consol] SET ([Measures].[Amount]"
    uMDX = uMDX + ",[Movements].[Monthly Movement].[Financial Day].&[" & cellX.Offset(0, -3).Value & 
    "]"
    uMDX = uMDX + ",[Transaction Detail].[Transaction ID].&[" & cellX.Value & "]"
    uMDX = uMDX + ") = " & cellX.Offset(0, -2).Value
    uMDX = uMDX + " USE_EQUAL_ALLOCATION"
    UpdateStatement = uMDX
    s = uMDX
    Print #n, s
    cn.Execute UpdateStatement
    uMDX = ""
    uMDX = uMDX + "UPDATE CUBE [Finance - Divisional] SET ([Measures].[Amount]"
    uMDX = uMDX + ",[Movements].[Monthly Movement].[Financial Day].&[" & cellX.Offset(0, -3).Value & 
    "]"
    uMDX = uMDX + ",[Transaction Detail].[Transaction ID].&[" & cellX.Value & "]"
    uMDX = uMDX + ") = " & cellX.Offset(0, -2).Value
    uMDX = uMDX + " USE_EQUAL_ALLOCATION"
    UpdateStatement = uMDX
    s = uMDX
    Print #n, s
    cn.Execute UpdateStatement
    ctr = ctr + 1
  End If
  Next cellX

 Sheets("Data").Calculate
  If ctr > 0 Then
   CommitStatement = "COMMIT TRAN"
   cn.Execute CommitStatement
 End If

 Else
```

Comment: For this range `Range("DB").Text` it is not specified in which worksheet that is. So that can be a cause of code sometimes working and sometimes not. It might sometimes take the wrong worksheet here. Make sure all objects that are located in a worksheet have a reference to a worksheet too! • Note that it is very hard to help you unless you can figure out what's going wrong and being able to reproduce it. You need to debug your code step by step using F8 and see what happens in the case of error.

Comment: Many thanks for your time. I will add reference to worksheets and let you know.

Comment: I tried couple of times to recreate the issue and unable to. I dont think the issue is with Range("DB").Text. The 2 cubes in the 1st For loop are updated and the other 2 cubes in the 2nd For loop of the IF block is not updated.

Comment: Well the rest  of the code doesn't look wrong (at least nothing obvious). So the only way to find out what is going wrong is probably you debuging the code. Go through it step by step using F8. Use the mouse to hold it over the variables of the active line to see the values (and if that is what you expect) or use the Local Window to investigate variables. That way you can find out where it is going wrong (other than you expected). Make sure you use `Option Explicit` and declare all variables to prevent typos you might not see.

Comment: When I debug the code, control is flowing through the code perfectly without issues. This issue is happening very rare and not always.

Comment: Well if you cannot reproduce (force) the issue it is very hard to find and even harder for us to tell what's wrong. There is nothing obvious in your code that can go wrong, so you need to do more investigations. For example code some logging to save date/time and `UpdateStatement` in a log file. So in case the update failed you see if the update even was triggered and what exactly the statement looked like when it went wrong. This way you maybe can find out some more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please help me how to code the log files.

Comment: You can either do it with `Debug.Print` (this will only live until you close Excel) or a hidden worksheet or a text file. For each of them you will find some tutorials either on Google or Stack Overflow. If you tried something and have a specific question please ask a new question with detailed information where you got stuck or errors.

Comment: I updated my code as above for log file. I could see that the data is written but for the print statement only half of the data is written. Why is this happening? for example, in the first for loop it is 1775112;Changed Value: 6898700;DB value: -2580635.2 and in the second for loop it is "1775112;Changed"... complete value is not written.